# Converting command line arguments to decimals in C

Tags: c

I am writing a program that takes command line arguments and performs basic arithmetic operations on them.  I am using `getopt` to get the arguments and I am storing them as strings.  Below are the variables I store the arguments in

```
char *distance = NULL;
char *time = NULL;
char *pace = NULL;
```

However how do I then convert them to decimals?  So for example "5" will become 5.00 or "6.12" will become 6.12.  I have tried search around but other solutions don't seem to work for me.

I have tried doing

```
double testnum;
testnum = atof(time);
```

but I get

error: request for member 'testnum' in something not a structure or a union

Comment: The error message you have does not match the code snippets you have shown. Please provide actual code that causes the error.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try strtof()

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
    {
        char *string, *stopstring;
        double x;
        float f;
        long double ld;

        string = "3.1415926This stopped it";
        f = strtof(string, &stopstring);
        printf("string = %s\n", string);
        printf("strtof = %f\n", f);
        printf("Stopped scan at \"%s\"\n\n", stopstring);
    }
```

Comment: +1 for proposing the only really usable approach.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `atof`:

```
double atof (const char* str);
```

Parses the C string str, interpreting its content as a floating point number and returns its value as a double.

It's not particularly robust though: in particular it returns zero if the input is not convertible, and *undefined behaviour* if the input number is too big.

Comment: I'd rather recommend [`strtof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) as it makes it easier to check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [atof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atof) function. it takes a char * and tries to parse a double.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

You can start off by scanf with the appropriate type.

```
scanf("%f", &time);
```

and then use `printf` to convert a type to a string when necessary.

If you do need to convert types from string, look for an `atoX` style function to do the conversion.  For example, here is a program that converts `a` (ascii) to `i` (integer)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   int val;
   char str[20];

   strcpy(str, "98993489");
   val = atoi(str);
   printf("String value = %s, Int value = %d\n", str, val);

   strcpy(str, "tutorialspoint.com");
   val = atoi(str);
   printf("String value = %s, Int value = %d\n", str, val);

   return(0);
}enter code here
```

Comment: You can have a look at the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392665/converting-string-to-float-without-atof-in-c

Comment: @Anand A while back, I too would re-implement functions that were available.  It is an excellent way to learn a few types of things.  It is also an excellent way to waste time and introduce unexpected behavior (bugs) when a less costly alternative exists.  There may be times when one really does need a new wrinkle on an old function, but mostly such things can be managed by composition of the old functions into routines.  Outside of those very special circumstances, it is generally better to reuse standard functions.

Answer (score 0):

The example code you provide does not match the error you have. The error tells us that `testnum` is not found *in a structure*.

I'm **guessing** you have a pointer to the structure and use non-pointer `.` to access the member. *Or* that you have a non-pointer structure and use pointer `->` to access the member.