# fgets() and floats on C

Tags: c

I have to read sentences from a `.txt` that look like this.

```
Pepe,Margal,Lopez,11111111A,1200.00
Laia,Rosa,Benita,22222222B,99000.20
```

Everything is fine when I read them with `fgets()`, but when I arrive to the comma before the `1200.00`or `99000.20` I need to convert them into floats.

I built this code for doing that.

```
float salary[5];

     ...(declaration of variables)

    do{
        while(line[b]!='\0'){
            if(line[b]=='.'){
                for(b;line[b]!='\0';b++){
                    salary[i]=salary[i]+(line[b]-'0')*0.1;
                    }
            }
            else{
                salary[i]=salary[i]*10+(line[b]-'0');
                b++;         
            }
        }
        i++;
    while(...);
```

(I can post the code if you ask me to do so).

When I printf("%.2f",salary[i]) with any value of i that is registered, I get an approximately quantity that I had. For example: with `1200.00` I'm getting `1999.80`.

I need to know if there is an easiest way to read a line, and convert that into float.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Did you try atof() function?

Comment: You might prefer `strtof()` - http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof.  By the way, it's not recommended to use floating point to represent currency amounts.

Comment: @Abend I didn't study that function, so I can't use it. My teacher has forbidden that to us.

Comment: Use `double` instead of `float`. Can you use `sscanf()`? `if (sscanf(line, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%lf", a, b, c, d, &salary) != 5) /* error */;`

Comment: @pmg No :(. I can only use `fread()`,`fseek()`,`fscanf()`,`fopen()`,`fclose()`,`fprintf()`,`fgets()`,`fgetc()`,`fwrite()`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Do you know any way to do this?

Comment: Then use `if (fscanf(file, " %[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%lf", a, b, c, d, &salary) != 5) /* error */;` or `if (sscanf(line, "%*[^,],%*[^,],%*[^,],%*[^,],%lf", &salary) != 1) /* error */;`

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior for floating point numbers.
See "[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)" for details -- or, better still: http://floating-point-gui.de/.

You'll also find that using floating point numbers for currency is not recommended because of the same imprecision.

---

In order to avoid implementation errors, consider replacing your algorithm with `strtof()` instead -- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof.

Comment: @BrianCain How do I use IEEE 754 on NetBeans?

Comment: IEEE 754 is the standard that almost all CPUs, compilers, etc conform to.  You're using it already by virtue of `float` or `double`.

Comment: @BrianCain And there's another way to `fscanf()` that value instead of using `fgets()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the standard library functions (which I highly recommend you do), this answer may help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4392789/5544939

Also, Brain Cain is right about using floating point for currency values.  Storing each salary in cents (int) instead of dollars would be safer.